# Can footers be added to MVCContrib grids?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I'd like for my column header to also be footers using MVCContrib grid.  How can I add footers?

```
<% Html.Grid(Model).Columns(col =>
{
col.For(c => c.sub_id).Named("Id");
col.For(c => c.name).Named("Name");
col.For(c => c.group).Named("Group");
col.For(c => c.insurance_GL).Named("Insurance").Format("{0:d}");
}).Attributes(id => "list").Render(); %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Out of the box there’s no built in way
>   to do this, but there are some
>   extensibility points you can hook into
>   if you want to add this functionality.
>
> If you create a custom GridRenderer
>   that inherits from HtmlTableGridRender
>   then you could override the
>   RenderGridEnd method and generate the
>   appropriate HTML in there.
>   - Jeremey Skinner

From comments in http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/03/01/mvccontrib-grid-part-5-the-action-syntax/

Comment: Thank you.  I actually looked at that page, but didn't go through the comments.